# Content missing after data center move

Tags: support

I had a answer to [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/637/anyone-know-more-social-games-like-werewolves) on [boardgames.se](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) (private beta) that I took several hours to compose (it was fairly long and comprehensive, and I had to go grab dinner in the middle of composing it). When I finished it, it posted just fine, though it may have already been in the middle of the data center move; I'm not sure. The answer showed up on the static site during the data center move, but then after the site went live again, it was gone. The answer URL was [this (extracted from my browser cache)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/637/anyone-know-more-social-games-like-werewolves/672#672), but that points just to the question now, my answer is missing.

I have managed to recover the answer from my browser cache, and run that through an HTML to Markdown converter, so I can re-post it. However, I'm wondering if there is some part of the migration that is not yet complete that is intended to pick up this missed content. I'm pretty sure there was also a comment that I made which is now missing (which is less important than the answer), and given that I experienced this I would be surprised if no one else did.

I [asked about this](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1383845452/datacenter-move-engage#disqus_thread) on the datacenter move thread, but I haven't heard anything about it there (someone hypothesized that there might be another pass of moving data over, but that was 9 hours ago and it hasn't reappeared yet), so I want to see if anyone here has any insight. Is the move done completely now, or is it still in progress? Will any of this lost content be retrieved, or do I need to dig what I can out of my caches and repost it?

Comment: I noted the same issue at http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/475/lost-answers-during-server-migration

Comment: A bunch of my StackOverflow reputation just disappared. I was at over 7800, and it just dropped to 7432.

Comment: @Ken: Wow - that's more than a day's cap worth of rep.

Answer (score 1):

If your post took quite some time to post it is very possible that you posted to our OR datacenter after we switched to read only mode - but prior to the site moving to NY.

The good news is that we have the post - the bad news is that it's in OR and not NY.  We can put it back up for you or you can go ahead and post again.

Comment: Since I've already recovered it, and re-Markdownified it, I might as well just re-post it. But I'm concerned about anyone else in the same boat, such as Ken Bloom from the comments above.

Comment: We will address any issues on a case by case basis.

Comment: I've re-posted my answer, so I'm all set now: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/637/anyone-know-more-social-games-like-werewolves/687#687

Comment: Please recover mine.

Comment: @Ken - I pulled up the old SO in OR, prior to the migration we show a rep of:  7397 and currently we show 7481.  You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation/user/197788 to see your reputation history.  This history is what would apply if we were to relcalc your rep right now.

Comment: @Geoff: OK, I guess I must have misremembered (confused the 3 for an 8). Sorry to bother you about the reputation. Were you able to find the answers and comments that I posted that were lost?